# Use matlab in makefiles etc. How to speed things up?

Tags: command-line, compile, matlab, makefile

I use a lot of matlab to process data etc. Yet I find my workflow a bit of sluggish, so I was wondering if I could speed things up a little using makefiles.

What I would like to do is write an `.m` file which, when called, creates a file with all of my data output, so that I can use the data in other programs. I would like to add a line to my makefile then:

```
output.dat: input.dat process1.m process2.m
        $MATLABROOT/matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r 'var1=process1;process2(var1);quit()'
```

yet it seems to me there base to be a better way. The problem here is that it takes a long while for matlab to start up, and it has to be started every time `output.dat` is regenerated (even when my actual matlab code didn't change).

Is there a way to easily get some sort of *compiled* matlab form of the `.m` files? Like one would have with a `c++` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/mcc.html)**

> mcc is the MATLAB command that invokes MATLAB Compiler. You can issue
>   the mcc command either from the MATLAB command prompt (MATLAB mode) or
>   the DOS or UNIX command line (standalone mode).
>
> mcc prepares MATLAB file(s) for deployment outside of the MATLAB
>   environment, generates wrapper files in C or C++, optionally builds
>   standalone binary files, and writes any resulting files into the
>   current folder, by default.

Comment: Could you please explain what this is and how it helps, instead of just dumping a link?

Comment: @nhinkle: TBH, I was planning on just dumping a comment.

Comment: gareth's edits made it much better, as an example of how you can turn a mere link into a decent answer.